# Сортировка столбцов матрицы по убыванию

Tags: c++

Написал сортировку пузырьком, но сортировка работает не правильно. В чем проблема?

```
void AddMatrx()
{
    srand(time(0));
    cout << "введите размерность массива" << endl;
    cin >> N >> M;
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j<M; j++)
            Matrx[i][j] = 0 + rand() % 200 - 100;
}
void PrintMatrx()
{
    cout << "Сформированный массив" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            cout << Matrx[i][j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
}
void SortMatrx()
{
    cout << "Сортировка столбцов по убыванию" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < M - 1; ++j) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; ++i) 
        {
            if (Matrx[i][j] < Matrx[i+1][j])
            {
                obm = Matrx[i+1][j];
                Matrx[i+1][j] = Matrx[i][j];
                Matrx[i][j] = obm;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    AddMatrx();
    PrintMatrx();
    SortMatrx();
    PrintMatrx();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Процедура SortMatrx выполняет лишь один проход по каждому столбцу, а сортировка пузырьком подразумевает два вложенных цикла. Поэтому сортировка и не закончена.